# How to Create videos with Stupeflix and Asp.Net (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, video-processing

I am working on a project to create videos from a series of images, videos and audios. The best API we could find online that suits our purpose was [Stupeflix](https://studio.stupeflix.com). Unfortunately [Stupeflix](https://studio.stupeflix.com) doesn't come with a C# implementation examples. Since I couldn't find one online, I decided to put this question here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

1. Go https://developer.stupeflix.com/ and register for Api Key and Secret
2. Create an ASP.NET project in C#
3. Go to NuGet Packages Manager and add `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` and `Json.NET`
4. Add Default page to your project and add `Async="true"` to the page declaration
5. Copy the code below and replace **YourSecret** with your Stupeflix secret.

   ```
   using Newtonsoft.Json;
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Net.Http;
   using System.Net.Http.Headers;

   namespace StupeflixTest
   {
       public class TaskObj
       {
           public Dictionary<string,string> tasks { get; set; }
           public TaskObj(Dictionary<string, string> t)
           {
               tasks = t;
           }
       }
       public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
       {
           private const string URL = "https://dragon.stupeflix.com/";
           protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               string error = string.Empty;
               try
               {
                   Dictionary<string, string> taskParam = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                   taskParam.Add("task_name", "video.create");
                   taskParam.Add("definition", "<movie service='craftsman-1.0'> <body> <stack> <sequence> <effect type='sliding' duration='5.0'> <image filename='http://s3.amazonaws.com/stupeflix-assets/apiusecase/Canyon_Chelly_Navajo.jpg'/> <image filename='http://s3.amazonaws.com/stupeflix-assets/apiusecase/Ha_long_bay.jpg'/> <image filename='http://s3.amazonaws.com/stupeflix-assets/apiusecase/Monument_Valley.jpg'/> </effect> </sequence> </stack> </body></movie>");
                   TaskObj obj = new TaskObj(taskParam);
                   //uncomment the line below to see the resultant json object
                   //string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

                   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Secret YourSecret");
                   client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

                   // await response.
                   var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("v2/create", obj);  // Blocking call!
                   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                   {
                       var jsonResp = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                       var jsonArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonResp);
                       string resultKey = jsonArray[0].key.Value;
                       string taskProgressUrl = URL + "v2/status?tasks=" + resultKey;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       error = string.Format(@"{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
                   }
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   error = ex.Message;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Are you connected with Stupeflix in any way?

Comment: @user890255 What does "not really" mean? Is it yes, or no? If you have no affiliation with their organization, then say "no". If you have some affiliation, then you should disclose what that is.

Comment: No I do not have any affiliation! I was searching for a very good API that I can use in my project with a minimal effort. I only have a three days old knowledge about Stupeflix.